# How to read the STORED logs from an attached device in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I need to read the logs that are stored in a device that I have attached by USB.  It's set up for debugging.  I run the Device File Explorer and it shows all the files.  But where are the log files hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the Android System does not keep a Log File, rather it has a temp buffer which contains logs.

**Approach 1:Write logs to file in internal storage through code**

You need to write logs to the device by yourself. There are libraries like [logback-android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) which can assist in doing so. You just need to create proper configuration in order to write logs on the device storage.

**Approach 2: Write logs to file using adb command**

Since you are connected through USB you can do

`adb logcat -d > logcat.txt`

The above command stores file on PC and not on device. Its in the same directory pointed by the command prompt

**Approach 3: Use Android Studio**

Connect your device to PC and run Android studio. At the bottom, you have logcat tab. You can view the logs and also save them to a text file.

---

Comment: I accept your answer that Android system does not keep a log file.  In this case, however, the device has crashed remotely with a worthless report in the Play Console.  I was hoping to connect the device to Android Studio and read the internal log from the device.  Thanks.

Comment: @BobLissner no problem. You can also implement crash analytics like hockeyapp or firebase. Then you can receive more details regarding crash.